# usync.nexage.com MS Edge Exploit?

Tags: malware, virus, microsoft-edge

Related to this question: [Is This A Hack/Malware/Breach?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/186342/is-this-a-hack-malware-breach/186352)

**Date**: Noticed between 5/23-5/24/2018

**OS**: Windows 10

**Applies to**: Windows 10 version 1709 for x64-based Systems

**Browser**: Microsoft Edge 41.16299.402.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299

A download pop up appears on KCRG.com (and other sites)  asking to download 
`mapuser?providerid=29472userid=`

From: `usync.nexage.com`

**Downloads**: Two files downloaded when saved. I did it twice. Both appear empty when opened with notepad.

[image: Two Files]

**Size of file**: 345 bytes

**Issue**: Download will be added to browser Downloads history. Unable to remove queued download from Downloads history. Clicking the item in the history does nothing. Closing browser gives a warning about downloads in progress.

If you interact with the pop-up dialog box you can save the files. Open button does the same as save.

It will not stay in Downloads history when browser is closed and reopened.

This issue may appear on other websites using the same advertising network.

1) Does this pose a threat?

2) Is this an MS Edge exploit?

This does not happen in Chrome or Firefox. At least on the computers I have tested.

3) Any solutions for the problem?

**New 5/26/2018**:  While checking Nexusmods.com per blib Edge version 42.17134.1.0 has caught and blocked content.

[image]

While checking PhotoBucket.com per Viking Knight, Edge version 42.17134.1.0 has caught and blocked Adobe Flash content.

[image]

In both cases no Download dialog box appeared and no download was added to Downloads history.

Comment: You are now providing the technical details that this issue requires. I'm curious, though: how do you come to the conclusion that this is the result of the new Windows update and is about the privacy experience?

Comment: Well, after the 0kb details, this looks like a bug in their ad network code.

Comment: Time table is the only thing that I have so far for my conclusion. The thought is the update causes Edge to catch a servlet causing the download prompt.

Comment: Updating system to Feature update for Windows 10, version 1803. MS Windows Edge is built into the OS. This will most likely fix the issue. Will post when complete. I'll be away so it'll be a while before I post.

Comment: While we normally do not handle this type of question, the fact that there is no known answer, the details are difficult to nail down, the threat level is unknown, and we are getting lots of people asking the very same question, I'm leaving this one open because it offers the most details and the OP is putting a ton of work in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Threat**: After testing, files have been found to be benign.

**Threat Level**: As stated this is more of an annoyance.

**Cuckoo Score**: (1.6 out of 10) This url shows some signs of potential malicious behavior.

http://cuckoo.cert.ee/analysis/2196788/summary

**Cause**: As mentioned, could be an Advertising Network code issue.

**Solution**: Updating to Windows 10, version 1803 solved the problem. MS Edge is built into Windows 10.

Latest Windows update as of May 2018:

[image: Windows 10 Update History, version 1803]

This updates Edge to:

[image]

Comment: Was able to update to the latest version of WIN10 and so far have not experienced a repeat of the problem. That being said, on at least 2 occasions the 1709 version of Edge was hijacked and bounced me to pages that MS had deemed unsafe to view. Therefore this should definitely be considered malware. Thanks for your help Rob0today.

Comment: @blib why do you think that this is related to your redirect experiences?

Comment: "Feature update", you know if they would actually be a little bit transparent about this, security people wouldn't have to lose their asses over it.

Comment: You can mark this as your accepted answer, now. Yes?

Comment: Sure will. Was wondering how far to chase the rabbit.

Answer (score -2):

I ran a "Reset PC" which is for Windows 10 (kinda like a W7/System Restore) 
That solved the problem, so far.

I found this option by putting the word "RESTORE" in the Windows search bar.

Comment: Right, that would be expected, because it rolls back the update. But is this thing being downloaded a risk? That's the question.

Comment: risk or not, it's not suppose to be there, I was disturbed by every time I closed all my windows, it said "still downloading, do you want to interrupt" which of course I wanted stopped completely ! as if it was pulling every single thing I had on my computer for God knows what, so either way, don't want it, I didn't ask for it, it's resistance to being deleted off recent downloads is very telling re; intentional maliciousness

Comment: lol glad I'm not the only one. I have noticed that this version of Edge is older. Why it was not updated in the latest updates is a mystery to me.

Comment: it just came back when I opened photobucket, had you visited photobucket lately or ran across one of it's HTML pictures

Comment: @VikingKnight "not wanting it" does not mean that it is malicious. A bug in the download process does not mean that it is malicious. Just annoying.

Comment: Have not visited photobucket. This issue is persistent. Has shown up while visiting foxnews.com as well. I believe as schroeder has pointed out that this looks to be a code issue with the ad network. How this could be used is concerning.

Comment: @Rob0today nothing concerning, just normal ad network stuff.

Comment: @Rob0today I got it going to yahoo news since noted photobucket trigger & I think once at Fox News too. I agree w/ you

Comment: @VikingKnight The updated Edge just caught and blocked content on nexusmods.com. Happened once so far and have yet to replicate